# How can we disable a .NET WebForms (.aspx file) LinkButton in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, css

I need to disable a LinkButton in a .aspx file using jQuery depending on the value. The button gets disabled in IE 8. But in Google Chrome it is not disabled.

Code:

```
$(".grid-prev-btn").addClass('ui-state-disabled').attr('disabled', true);
```

Please give me solution for this issue

I am trying to disable link button for a particular condition it gets disabled in Internet Explorer but in Chrome browser it not getting disabled

Answer (score 0):

ok, really you should be using `prop` instead of `attr` for recent implementations of jQuery

```
$(".grid-prev-btn").addClass('ui-state-disabled').prop('disabled', true);
```

attr would be more applicable to the written disabled="disabled" attribute on a tag, so should more correctly be `.attr("disabled", "disabled")`

However, disabled on  hyperlinks isn't supported on modern browsers, so I'd suggest the following. The `.attr`, disabling `pointer-events` and adding a click handler for should the link be triggered by the keyboard

As you are using jQuery 1.8.x, I would recommend the full solution as follows.

```
$(".grid-prev-btn").addClass('ui-state-disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled').css('pointer-events', 'none').on("click", function() { return false; });
```

You could of course remove the `pointer-events` bit from inline, and put it in your CSS for `.ui-state-disabled`

```
a.ui-state-disabled { pointer-events: none; }
```

Comment: Thank You for the response, I tried your solutions but it not working on chrome

Comment: what element is `.grid-prev-btn`? Is it a `<button>`, an `<a>` link, or something else? And do you know what version number of jQuery you are using @RUTUJAPARAB?

Comment: It is <asp:LinkButton> and JQuery version is 'jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css'

Comment: ah, ok, that renders as an `<a>` link, which doesn't support `disabled` in modern browsers. I have amended my answer with a better solution @User1998

Comment: Thank you so much for your support it is working now but facing issue with pointer i added that in css but still page continuously loading can you please suggest any other alternative for 'pointer-events'?

Comment: what happens if you just use `$(".grid-prev-btn").addClass('ui-state-disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled').on("click", function() { return false; });` @User1998?

Comment: I tried that but it not getting disabled after remove that pointer

Comment: so what is the problem with the full solution, I do not understand what you mean by "facing issue with pointer i added that in css but still page continuously loading" @User1998

Comment: actually at time of page load properly and this button is disabled but suppose it getting unable for certain condition and i clicked on that button at that time page is just getting loaded means i showing buffering symbol. only that is issue otherwise your code work perfectly.

Comment: I think you need to post some code to your Question, or point us to a test URL for further help, so as we can understand the problem better @User1998

Comment: Ok I will share thanks